# Creating a desktop widget application

Tags: windows, widget

I am new to all this, but I would like to create a widget application on the desktop, similar to how rainmeter can work, but from scratch. I would like to use applications like java, python, or C#, but if there is a method for C or C++, I am fine using that too. Does anyone have a good idea on how to start with this?